# Experimental design type?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, descriptive-statistics

A pencil depth tester is used for various pieces of paper. Two different pencils are used.
The class measures how deep the pencils go into the various pieces of paper.

Paper  Pencil  Depth

```
1      2        5
2      1        3
3      1        2
4      2        6
5      2        7
6      1        8
7      2        2
8      1        9
```

What type of experimental design is used?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a somewhat strange design.

It does not make much sense in an industrial setting: do you really want to generalize to the population of papers to compare the effect of two very specific pencils? You could not say anything about the pencil brand (unless the pencils of the brand are completely identical, but then the variance would have to come from the measurement procedure and you would want to generalize to the population of measurements of one specific pencil..). You would much rather measure the average depth for a pencil given several trials and using several pencils. If the paper number mattered or would indicate a different type of paper, then each piece of paper would have to be used with each pencil... Those two specific pencils must be very important to you that you would waste eight sheets of papers to be able to make statements confined to these two unique pencils (judging from the results it also looks a lot more like a random textbook problem)...

Comment: It's marked self-study. Forget the experiment altogether, I'm talking about the statistical setup of subjecting various samples to two different treatments as shown above.

Comment: but why did you choose this particular example, then? It would be easier and less confusing to reframe the question with standard observational units (paper [sheets?] are a strange sample after all). As far I can see there are two samples of... sheets that does not undergo more than one treatment each in the example... But in a different frame you could consider the pencils to be sample out of a populaiton of pencils. You see, context matters for the answer. Is it a homework question?